# req.headres.Authorization is undifined in heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, axios

I have been working in react and express project every thing work perfectly in my local server but when I deploy it to heroku the header Authorization where I set the auth jwtToken  don't work
when I reload the page I lost the headers. this the link to my project https://immense-coast-59384.herokuapp.com  you can try it.

## this my auth middleware

```
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
       const token =  req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret);
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })

        if (!user) {
            throw new Error()
        }
        
        req.token = token
        req.user = user
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate.' })
    }
}
```

I use this middleware lisk this in my express route ex:

```
router.get('/users/me', auth, async (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user)
})
```

my client side React request ex:

```
 const  getMe = async ()=>{
     
        try {
           
          const token = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
         
          const res = await axios.get(
              `/users/me`,
              {
                  headers:{  "Authorization" :`Bearer ${token}` },
               
                }
              )
          setUser(user=>({...user,userInfo:res.data}))
      
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
```

this is a screenshot of my heroku logs [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMQbr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku have limitation for the header size.If the requests containing a request line or header line longer than 8KB will be dropped by the router without being dispatched.

> **From Heroku**
>
> When processing an incoming request, a router sets up an 8KB receive
>   buffer and begins reading the HTTP request line and request headers.
>   Each of these can be at most 8KB in length, but together can be more
>   than 8KB in total. Requests containing a request line or header line
>   longer than 8KB will be dropped by the router without being
>   dispatched.

For more info read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#request-buffering

Comment: is there is a way to reduce the size of the request header?

Comment: try to reduce the content inside the jwt token,

Comment: I only put the user id inside the token and still not working !!!